# Algorithm run-time complexity recursion BIG-O

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I understand the concept of the Big O notation and its something i've brought upon myself to learn recently.

But say for a given algorithm, which recursively calls itself until the job is complete, if there is an OR in my return statement, how will that effect the Big O notation?

**Here's the algorithm thus far:**

```
**Algorithm: orderedSort(a,b,c)**
given strings a,b,c determine whether c is an ordered shuffle of a and b

l := length of (a + b)
if (l = 0) then
    return true
if (l not = length of c)
    return false
else
    d := substring of a position 1 to 1
    e := substring of b position 1 to 1
    f := substring of c position 1 to 1
if (d = f) then 
    return orderedSort(a-d, b, c-f) 
if (e = f) then
    return orderedSort(a, b-e, c-f)
if (d and e = f) then
    return orderedSort(a-d, b, c-f) or orderedSort(a, b-e, c-f)
```

Does having the or make it n^2?

Comment: You need to identify the worst possible sequence of recursive calls that the function can generate. i.e. find the worst possible inputs for `a,b,c` which will yield the most calls.

Comment: And how do I do that @oarfish

Comment: Looks like there is something missing in your algorithm?

Comment: whats that? @gnasher729

Comment: 1. If d = f or e = f then the third if is never reached. 2. After the third if, there is no return statement. Further, if l = 0 then "true" is most likely the wrong answer, say a = "x", b = "y", c = "xyz".

Comment: i meant to put the last if statement 1st and 
if L not = length of c removes his other problem

Answer (score 1):

It's far worse than you think.  If both halves of the "or" will need to be evaluated some % of the time, then you will end up with O(2^n) (not O(n^2)) recursive calls.

Let's say it takes both halves of the OR 10% of the time.  On average you have to go down 10ish levels before you do both halves, so you have around:

```
1 call with length n
2 calls with length n-10
4 calls with length n-20
8 calls with length n-30
...
2^(n/10) calls with length 0
```

Also, it's worse than that again, because all those string manipulations (length(a+b), a-d, etc.) take O(n) time, not constant time.

EDIT: I should mention that O(2^n) is not actually correct.  It's "exponential time", but O(2^(n/10)) or whatever is strictly less than O(2^n).  A correct way to write it is 2^O(n)

EDIT:

A good solution for this problem would use dynamic programming.

Let OK(i,j) = true if the first i+j characters of c are an ordered shuffle of the first i characters of a and the first j characters of b.

OK(i,0) is easy to calculate for all i.  Then you can calculate all the OK(i,j) from OK(i,j-1).  When you've covered all the cases with i+j = length(c), then return true if any one of them is true.